# PHP Radio button form handling

Tags: php

I'm using radio buttons on a form for my website. I am currently trying to write some error checking. If the radio button isn't set when the form is submitted what will $_GET return? I tried echoing it and it appears to be "", but my if statement isn't picking up on it. Is it just not returning a value at all?

Comment: if the radio button is not chosen, it's empty, which will result in "". do a: `if (empty($_GET['radio_button']) { /* do something */ } else { /* do something */ }`

Comment: Can you share your code, please?

Comment: the name of `radio` button won't exist in `$_POST`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use form method as POST , using GET method in form submit is not good practice .
 If you are using POST method, you can check like below

```
if(!isset($_POST['radio_buttonname'])){
//Your error message set here
}
```

If you are using GET method.Use below code,

```
if(!isset($_GET['radio_buttonname'])){
//Your error message set here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

when radio button is not selected it is not set in the $_GET. Do this

```
$radion_value = isset($_GET['radio_button_name']) ? true : false;
if($radio_value){
// value is set 
}
else { 
// not set
}
```